# Can't have value stored in Rails.cache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, memcached

I have a memcached container and a Rails App.

If a I have loop doing this:

```
100.times do
  puts Rails.cache.read('yes')
  sleep(0.5)
end
```

And I open the Rails console to write into the cache

```
Rails.cache.write('yes', 'value')
```

I will still have a nil value in my put.

But if a write/read from the console or directly from the app, it works well.

What I am doing wrong ? Or what did I miss ?

Thanks in advance

Here's the configuration of memcached in my production.rb file

```
config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store, ENV['MEMCACHED_HOST']
```

More info:
If I write into the cache and launch the app, it will catch the value.

Both Rails app and Memcached are Docker containers.

```
Rails version: 5.1.5

Ruby version: 2.5.0

Gem Dalli version: 2.7.8

Memcached version: 1.5.10

Docker version: 18.03.1
```

Comment: Is there a chance you're not booting rails console with correct RAILS_ENV?

Comment: The env is good. If I first write in the console to the cache and then launch the app, it works fine as well.

Comment: Where did you run the loop? I have tested on my machine using your code and it is working normally.

Comment: The Rails app is in a docker container, I ran the console from the container using "bundle exec rails c"